# Scrollbar in UIScrollView and UIWebview

Tags: xcode, uiwebview, uiscrollview, scrollbars

I've been searching for some time for an answer on this problem: 
How can I keep the scrollbars on my UIScrollView and UIWebview visible? So that the user knows he can scroll up or down. (like in firefox or any other browser so without touching the scrollvie first)

I read on some sites that it wasn't possible, so my other question would be: 
Is there a way to add a "scrollbar" to a scrollview or webview?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you could use this: 
flashScrollIndicators

It won't show the scrollbar all the time, but it just flashes when the view is loaded.

Edited: Other solution:

In your view didload, you make a scrollview of you webview like this: 
UIScrollview *scrollview = [webview.subviews objectAtindex:0];

you have to set the delegate of the scrollview on self: 
scrollview.delegate= self

in your .h file you add

When you place in your .m file you can use: 
-(void)ScrollviewDidscroll:...

(I don't know if it works when you have multiple scrollviews)

Comment: This is a good possibility, but The problem is that my start page has multiple view in a scrollview, but in those subviews there is also a scrollview. I used flashScrollIndicators in my start view, but the others won't show the flash because they are already loaded before I want to see them. But I will try to make a scrollbar myself and see how that goes. Thanks for the answer

Comment: Works only of the begging and on the end of content. And flashes too much times. Bad solution.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can try adding a custom view ( can be image view)  on top the scrollbar. You will have to monitor the `contentOffset` and `contentSize` to know where you are. Based on this information, you can position your custom scroll bars.

Comment: I'm going to try this one, I don't know if it will work, but thanks for the answer.